# a redirection to the profile

Tags: php, html

Ive got a code running smoothly which shows the list of people who are level 8 as shown below

[image]

I want when a person click on the username of the people it redirects them to their profile, actually i've got no clue or ideas of how could that be done. So i need a little bit of help to get some points on this.
Here is the code to show the above output

```
<?php

                  $lvl8 = 0;
                  $content = "";

                  $query = $koneksi->prepare("SELECT `user`, `level`, `LastOnlineDate` FROM `playerdata` WHERE `banned`=0 AND `level`=8");
                  $query->execute();
                  while($data = $query->fetch())
                  {
                     $lvl8++;
                     $content .= "<tr><td>".$lvl8."</td>";
                     $content .= "<td>".$data['user']."</td>";
                     $content .= "<td>".$data['LastOnlineDate']."</td></tr>";
                  }

                ?>

                <table class="table table-bordered">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan='6'><h4><small>Level 8 - Trusted Admin (Total <?php echo $lvl8 ?>)</small></h4></td>
                    </tr>
                    <td><h5>Number</h5></td>
                    <td><h5>Username</h5></td>
                    <td><h5>Last Login</h5></td>
                  </thead>

                 <?php

                        if($query->rowCount() == 0)
                        {
                            echo "<tr><td colspan='6'><small>No rows found</small></td></tr>";
                        }


                        echo $content;

                        ?>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

first thing you should do is, have an a tag for name, like this

```
$content .= "<td><a href='link to a new file?id=userid from database'>".$data['user']."</a></td>";
```

In the new page, you can capture the id of the user, run a query to fetch the details of obtained id and then show the details obtained from database.

Answer (score 0):

Create a http query or post form for your action. 
like this in your foreach loop.
GET

```
<a href="youraction?user_id=<?php echo $userid?>"> <?php echo $username ?> </a>
```

in your ending script for example a controller in an mvc architecture:

```
$id = $_GET['user_id'];
// do database stuff and view
```

Do your query using $id and fetch the result then display your view.

Basically you iterate over user id's to create links that carry the id of the clicked user in order to fetch the selected id.